# VueJS2, how to call props in data

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vue-props

I created a component, I want to call the model value. If I do it the first way, but when I try to do it the second, I get this error.

```
[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')"
```

**The first way**

[image]

**The second way**

[image]

I want to use second way because i want create own component vuetify date-picker and i want to pass date to him.

Unless it is possible to rewrite the first one in such a way that I can write the date in this way. Is there any way to "vm"? I am using this https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/#formatting

[image]

Thank you for answering

Answer (score 2):

Vue automatically binds the regular functions that are provided to its `data` or `methods` sections to the component instance. However, arrow functions can not be bound - the `this` keyword inside arrow functions refers to the closest outer context/scope. But since there is no such context for the `data` section - your `this` is undefined.

You should either use a regular function instead of arrow function when defining your `data` section - or you should leave the values in the arrow function undefined and assign the initial values inside the `created` hook.

Answer (score 2):

You should use in arrow function like this.

```
props: ['value'],
data: vm => ({
  props: vm.value
});
```